# Running domain's tests in multi-module project with @SpringApplicationConfiguration throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have my multi-module project structured like this:

```
project-example (parent)
-- project-example-domain: contains DAOs and Services
-- project-example-service: contains Controllers
```

Service module has domain as dependency, so service knows domain, but not the other way around.

So, for testing ClientDAO integrity (in this case), i have this test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DAOConfiguration.class)
public class ClientDAOTests {

    @Autowired
    private ClientDAO dao;

    @Test
    public void testFindClient() {
          ...
    }

}
```

When i run it, i get this exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:533)
    ... 51 more
```

And finally my DAOConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:persistence.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.movies.domain.feature"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DAOConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.example.movies.domain"});
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return entityManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

When i run the server from the service it works fine, Spring makes the DataSource bean. But when i run my test in domain, i get the exception mentioned before.

So i think that my problem is that i am passing incorrect argument to @SpringApplicationConfiguration. I don't understand what do i have to pass... should i pass it the Application class with the @SpringBootApplication annotattion? In this case, this is inside Service module so domain doesn't know this class. Can you explain what does the SpringApplicationConfiguration should take as parameter that is making my test fail? Thanks in advance!

---

### EDIT

This is my ApplicationRunner class located in service layer:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ServicesConfiguration.class, CustomDataBindingConfiguration.class, CustomMappingConfiguration.class})
@PropertySource(value = {"application.properties"})
public class ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationRunner.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your DataSource bean defined? Why isn't it defined in the DAOConfiguration class, since that's where it's needed?

Comment: because Spring Boot builds it. That is way when i run the server, spring boot generates that bean reading properties specified in persistence.properties file (in this case). So apparently i am not running the test with Spring boot and that is the problem...

Comment: See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-configfileapplicationcontextinitializer-test-utility I guess it should solve the problem.

Comment: I think that the problem comes from the initializer, and not from the classes i am loading... I think that by some way i should pass the Application annotated with @SpringBootApplication located in service module (but i cannot do this because domain doesn't know service). What do you think?

Comment: Could you share the configuration class from the service layer?

Comment: What do you mean by the configuration class from the service layer? i have edited the post with my runner class from service layer if that is what you are asking me for. Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved the very same problem.

The problem comes from `@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = DAOConfiguration.class)`.
You have to reference a class annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration` for datasource to be automatically injected by Spring Boot. (this annotation is generally inherited from `@SpringBootApplication`)

You have several options :

- Reference your application class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` from `@SpringApplicationConfiguration`
- Add `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to `DAOConfiguration` class
- ... (you understand the point)

Comment: Ok. I don't even remember how i faced the problem finally (i have no access to that project anymore). But i accept your answer since it seems to be reasonable ;). Thanks!